# Line break in title of section

Tags: chapters

If I have a title very long in `\chapter`, how I can use two line?

for example:

```
\chapter{Apêndice A - Massa e frações das~amostras~separadas}
```

Comment: it looks very weird to have chapter 1 appendix a, shouldn't the markup be `\appendix  \chapter{Massa e frações das~amostras~separadas}` so latex writes the appendix 1 bit automatically?

Comment: David Carliste, this command \appendix \chapter{ is not accept for Texmaket, is does?

Comment: The editor you use to write the file is not relevant to the command definition. most classes with a `\chapter` define an `\appendix` command that makes later chapters use "appendix" rather than "Chapter" (in a suitable language) the standard `book` class for example.  But you have not shown any test file so impossible to guess an answer for the class you are using.

Comment: I see in comments on an answer you say you are using `book` so `\appendix` _is_ defined.

Answer (score 2):

You should allow latex to number appendices automatically, chapter titles will linebreak if too long:

[image]

```
\documentclass[openany,11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Zzzz}
aabbcc

\appendix

\chapter{Massa e frações das amostras separadas}
aaabbcc

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Chapter titles should automatically linebreak if they are too long. However, you can manually create a line break using `\\`.

```
\documentclass[openany,11pt,fleqn]{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title\\with a line break}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered LaTeX]

If you don't want to include the "Chapter 1" text use the `\chapter*` command:

```
\documentclass[openany,11pt,fleqn]{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Chapter without\\additional text}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered LaTeX]

Comment: Chrisma, I used \\, but it does not work!
I have Texmaker

Comment: @AlexanderRamírez Please provide use with more context in your question, so that it is easier to help you ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: @AlexanderRamírez: TeXmaker does nothing here – it's only a specialised editor with facilities for editing and compiling.

Comment: I'm a newbie, I'm using \documentclass[openany,11pt,fleqn]{book}. And I have different file for each chapters, appendix, etc..

Comment: @AlexanderRamírez `\documentclass{book}` should allow line breaks using '\\' (see my modified answer). Can you post a small compilable example that errors with you, i.e. an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?